# Reading output from batch file which runs a Python script

Tags: python

I have a batch file which runs a Python script. This script simulates data that is printed 3 lines at a time every 5 seconds. Below is the simple code I have.

```
while True:
    print("Some Data")
    print("More Data")
    print("Some More Data")

    time.sleep(5)
```

So, when running the batch file, these 3 lines are printed every 5 seconds in cmd. Is there a way for me to log these every 5 seconds to a single .txt file?

Comment: It would help if you showed us the batch file (or a stripped-down version).

Comment: Also, you say here that you have a batch file that runs a Python script. But in a comment on my answer, you say that you have a Python script that runs a batch file. Which one is it? Please read [mcve] in the help; it’s hard to know what needs to go into a question when you first start at SO, but the help does a pretty good job guiding you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to log these every 5 seconds to a single .txt file?

Yes. Two and a half ways, in fact.

---

First, you can modify the Python script to write to a text file instead of stdout:

```
with open('logfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    while True:
        print("Some Data", file=f)
        print("More Data", file=f)
        print("Some More Data", file=f)

        time.sleep(5)
```

---

Or, if you want to be able to pass it a filename instead of hardcoding `logfile.txt`:

```
import sys

filnename = sys.argv[1]
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    while True:
        print("Some Data", file=f)
        print("More Data", file=f)
        print("Some More Data", file=f)

        time.sleep(5)
```

Now your batch file would do this:

```
py myscript.py logfile.txt
```

---

Of course in both of these cases, you don't have to use the `file=` argument to `print`; you could instead use `f.write("Some Data\n")` directly if you need more control over the file, or use [the `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) to magically do fancier logging (e.g., with automatic timestamps).

---

Alternatively, you can leave the Python script alone, and instead modify the batch file to use [shell redirection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout):

```
py myscript.py >logfile.txt
```

Comment: Ok . I guess I should elaborate a bit further. My Python script just simulates what I would see the output as. So, going into the Python script and writing to a file wouldn't solve my problem. What I need to do is read from the batch file which produces these 3 lines every 5 seconds and log them to a .txt file

Comment: @ArthurBuczynski Please edit your question to be closer to what you’re actually asking, and to have enough information to be answerable. But if I can take a wild guess: you’re probably running the batch script with `os.system`? If you read the docs for that function, it will explain that you want to use the `subprocess` module instead, and link you to the right place to find explanations and examples. I could find you a duplicate question here that covers the same ground, but in this case, the actual docs are a whole lot better.